# List all dotfiles current directory using zsh

Tags: shell, zsh, wildcards

How can I list all dotfiles in a directory using zsh.?

Comment: `ls -a` , it's not related to zsh  , `-a` show dot files.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The classic way we used to do it back in the day was:

```
ls .??*
```

This would list all dotfiles but not include `.` or `..`.  Of course, whomever came up with this assumed that all dotfiles would be named with two or more characters after the `.`.

The other weakness is if you have directories that start with `.` then that command will list the contents of it.  That aspect can be fixed by using the `-d` flag for `ls`.  That tells `ls` to just show any directories specified on the command line without delving into them.

Nowadays, most versions of `ls` include the `-A` flag which will list all dotfiles in the directory but excluding `.` or `..`.  And you don't have to worry about putting a `-d` flag on there.

Comment: And you can correct the first aspect with something like `ls .[^.]*`

Comment: Somehow when I use these, I am getting internal listing of the dot-directories as well, which I want to avoid. I would like to avoid that. the ```printf '%s\n' .*(.)``` syntax seems to avoid that.

Comment: @nobuzz you could use `ls -d .[^.]*`; at least with GNU ls, the `-d` option means 'don't go into directories'.

Comment: @nobuzz As I mentioned, the `-d` option stops that.  (evilsoup mentioned it again just above.)

Comment: In zsh, `.*` excludes `.` and `..`, so no special care is necessary. In other shells, you would need also `.[!.]` for dot files with just two characters.

Answer (score 8):

Not only [zsh](/questions/tagged/zsh) :

```
printf '%s\n' .*
```

(though beware that some shells other than `zsh` will include `.` and `..` in that list)

With zsh syntax, restricting to *regular* files only:

```
printf '%s\n' .*(.)
```

To list all files *including* hidden ones:

```
printf '%s\n' *(D)
```

`D` for *dot* (hidden) files.

Comment: This will include `.` and `..`, which will be fine for just listing things but might cause issues in scripts.

Comment: Not for me. And with the added command ?

Comment: I'm using bash; I've just checked with zsh and it seems you are correct (both of your commands work fine there). It still seems worth mentioning that different shells will handle this in different ways.

Comment: This seems to work. However if I do ```ls .*(.)``` I seem to get a very truncated list of dotfiles. Why would that be?

Comment: @evilsoup `.*` includes `.` and `..` in all shells except zsh, where they are always omitted from globs.

Answer (score 5):

zsh comes shipped with `ls -a` and `ls -A` that are of great help!

`ls -a` lists all items (files and directories) in a directory
`ls -A` does the same, but does *not* list `.`and `..`.

You can go to your `.zshrc` config file and create aliases to make these commands easier to run. I aliased mine this way:

```
alias l='ls -l'         # ls with items and directory details
alias la='ls -a'        # ls all items and directories within cd
alias lA='ls -A'        # ls all items and directories within cd, EXCEPT "." and ".."
alias lla='ls -la'      # combines "ls -l" and "ls -a"
alias llA='ls -lA'      # combines "ls -l" and "ls -A"
```

And the output is the following:

[image: la and lA aliases in function]

---

Also, if you want to display files icons you can simply install the following plugin, **ls deluxe**, from [here](https://github.com/Peltoche/lsd). Many use **colorls**, but **ls deluxe** is written in Rust and is sensibly faster.

I added this alias in my `.zshrc` so that anytime I run `ls` I am instead running `lsd`.

```
alias ls='lsd'
```

Comment: Note that `ls` has nothing to do with `zsh`, `zsh` doesn't have a `ls` builtin.